# SML/NJ - Effective way or data structure to access from end towards the start

Tags: list, sml

I am making a program, and an algorithm I have thought to use requires a cheap way of accessing a list backwards to be effective. Is there an effective way to access a list from the last element forward? Or, because I think that might be impossible due to the structure of SML lists, is there an effective data structure to achieve it?

The length of data is unknown before executing, and there is no need for other than serial traversing of the data.

Comment: you must be leaving something out, because why can't you just re-define the front as the back, and access it forwards?

Comment: I want to be able to access the list backwards while still being able to access it the normal way from the front side - in a few words, I want to have bidirectional access. In theory, a doubly linked list would be perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want a functional deque. See e.g. [Okasaki's paper on the subject](http://www.westpoint.edu/eecs/SiteAssets/SitePages/Faculty%20Publication%20Documents/Okasaki/jfp95queue.pdf). Specifically, Figure 5 shows an implementation of deques.

Answer (score 0):

If using a functional deque seems like overkill and you need to traverse the list in reverse order just once, then solutions that e.g. use `List.last` and `List.take` to emulate `hd` and `tl` but in reverse order are, as you seem to know, bad because they would make the list traversal quadratic. On the other hand, the built in function `rev` is very efficient since it is both tail-recursive and linear. If you feed a list to a function that needs to traverse that list in reverse order, an easy solution is to use a `let` binding using `rev` to create a local copy of the list in reverse order and then traverse the reversed list in the usual way.

Comment: I did have these in mind, but there will be continuous reads of different lists backwards, and continuous reversions would be too slow. On the other hand, using a functional deque was indeed overkill, so I came up with a new algorithm :P but learning about functional dequeues made the question worthwhile.